# react-hook-form when editing doesn't update

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I can't find a way to provide the existing information from the DB to the `react-hook-form` library to revalidate when clicking submits and to update it if the data was changed.

The problem is when clicking on `submit` button, this object will shown without any value for `firstName` and `lastname`:

`{firstName: undefined, lastname: undefined}`

Simplified version of my component:

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core";

const App = (props) => {
  const { register, handleSubmit} = useForm();

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);   // ---> here
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <h2>Step 1</h2>
      <label>
        First Name:
        <TextField {...register("firstName")} defaultValue="firstname" />
      </label>
      <label>
        Last Name:
        <TextField {...register("lastname")} defaultValue="lastname" />
      </label>
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
};

export default App
```

Any idea how to create a form that allows you to edit the fields?

Check out on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-wizard-form-forked-37fs9?file=/src/Step1.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the `TextFiled` component. the `register` is not set correctly.

According to the `MUI` [documentation](https://mui.com/api/text-field/):

> props:inputProps  type:object description:Attributes applied to the input element.

So you need to pass the `register` throw the `inputProps`:

```
<TextField inputProps={register("firstName")} defaultValue="firstname" />

<TextField inputProps={register("lastname")} defaultValue="lastname" />
```